# Как лучше работать со словарем

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть метод, на вход подается простой словарь (Dictionary cars), который содержит цвет и модель(key-color, values-model).
мне нужно нарисовать таблицу в которой будет 2 столбца цвет и модель.

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> cars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    cars.Add("green", "bmw");
    cars.Add("white", "ford");
    cars.Add("black", "audi");

    DrawTable(cars);
}
private IActionResult DrawTable(Dictionary<string, string> cars)
{
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table><tbody><tr>");
    foreach (var model in cars.Values)
      {
         sb.Append(String.Format("<td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td>", **cars.Keys**, model);
      }
    sb.Append("</tr></tbody></table>");
    var table = sb.ToString();
    return Content(table);
}
```

но таким образом в первую колонку попадут все цвета, а мне нужно конкретный для этого авто.
как лучше нарисовать эту таблицу?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то нужно: `foreach (var model in cars) sb.Append(String.Format("<td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td>", model.Key, model.Value))`. И словарь совершенно не подходит для решения этой задачи.

Comment: а как тогда лучше? через list?

Comment: Да, любая плоская структура - лист, массив. В качестве элемента используйте класс с нужными вам свойствами - цвет, марка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понял то:

```
public string DrawTable(Dictionary<string, string> cars)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table><tbody><tr>");
    foreach (var color in cars.keys)
      {
         sb.Append(String.Format("<td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td>", color, cars[color]);
      }

    sb.Append("</tr></tbody></table>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Правда соглашусь с предыдущими ораторами - думаю стоит создать отдельную модель или как вариант можно анонимный тип:

```
var cars = new { Brand = "BMW", Color = "green" };
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас код содержит много синтаксических ошибок, похоже вы пишете в блокноте без проверки компилятором (Add с большой буквы, строки в кавычках и т.п.)

Также вам надо подтянуть понимание Dictionary, какие у него есть методы работы.

Код будет примерно такой:

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> cars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    cars.Add("green", "bmw");
    cars.Add("white", "ford");
    cars.Add("black", "audi");

    DrawTable(cars, "green").Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public string DrawTable(Dictionary<string, string> cars, string selectedCarName)
{
    if(!cars.ContainsKey(selectedCarName))
        return string.Empty; // maybe null or throws

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table><tbody><tr>");
    sb.Append(String.Format("<td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td>", selectedCarName, cars[selectedCarName]));

    sb.Append("</tr></tbody></table>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отдельно нужно понимать, что в вашем вопросе неявно подразумевается что у одного цвета может быть только одна машина. Вообще-то это в общем случае и в реальных приложениях не так.

Comment: прям тут писала, сорян за ошибки. Получается если у меня таблица из 50 марок, то мне надо 50 раз вызывать DrawTable(), а как можно это обыграть?